# Using gikom openfire REST API when hit using the php code , the error appears as 401 unauthorized

Tags: php, rest, openfire

PHP code that gives the 401 unauthorized.

The Rest API authorities have been enabled and also a secret key has been given for auth.

Answer (score 0):

The http response code 401 says that the provided secret key is wrong or simply not right in place. It needs to be in the header param of the request.

Comment: @RajeskwarBose what is the PHP code you use?  Can you post it?